# How to set bearer token in RequestSpecification spec builder in restAssured java

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I am trying to add my bearer token in the `RequestSpecBuilder` where my specbuilder
looks like

```
public static RequestSpecification requestSpecBuilderWithAuthorization(String baseURL, AuthenticationScheme auth) {
    RequestSpecification req = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri(baseURL)
            .setContentType(ContentType.JSON).setAccept("*/*")
            .setAuth(auth)
            .build();
    return req;
}
```

And let say I have a bearer token as "bearer ". So my main objective here is to pass bearer token in `RequestSpecification`.

So how can I pass this token as a `AuthenticationScheme` in `setAuth(`) or is it even possible to parameterised a `specBuilder` where I can pass bearer token.

Comment: a simple solution will be to directly add the authorization header before calling .build() ```.addHeader("Authorization", "bearer eyJhbGciOiJFZERTQSJ9").build()```. Other options would b to set your user and password pass them through this `AuthenticationScheme auth` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your token in header.

`req.header("Authorization", "Bearer <your_token_here>");`